# How to show/hide certain number of elements from a list using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am trying to paginate a long list using plain javascript. I could successfully hide all the elements in the list, but how do I show certain number of them?

Assuming each page should have maximum 10 elements. I created a function which takes a pageNumebr. I can hide all the elements, but apparently looping or using subscript on the result of `document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0]` does not work.

```
var students = document.getElementsByClassName("student-list")[0]


// function to hide all of the items in the list 
// except for the ten I want to show

function showPage(pageNumber) {
  students.style.visibility = "hidden"

  // how do I iterate over students and show 10 elements only ?

  // the following logs a list of ul elements
  console.log(students);

  // but the following gives me undefined, So I can't loop over students
  console.log(students[0]);

}

showPage(3)
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("student-list")[0]` returns one `ul`, this is why you can't loop over it. It's _one_ element. Instead, select all the `li`s that are inside. Give your `li`s a class and select this class.

Comment: I see your point. Actually my li s already have a class. I used that, and I can loop over the HTML collection now.